Competing risk - cumulative incidence in a weighted population
I have the following data which has been weighted, based on the propensity score.
The only independent variable of interest in the model is treat as covariates have been balanced using weights.
The event of interest is a disease.
The competing risk is death.
Thus, event == 0 (censored), event == 1 (disease), event == 2 (death).
library(cobalt)
library(cmprsk)
library(survminer)

set.seed(123)
lalonde <- cbind(lalonde,
                 event = sample(c(0, 1), size = 614, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.84, 0.16)),
                 time = runif(614, min = 10, max = 365))
n <- ceiling(0.05 * nrow(lalonde))  
selected_indices <- sample(1:nrow(lalonde), size = n)
lalonde[selected_indices, "event"] <- 2


formula <- treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75 + re78

# PS
lalonde$pscore <- glm(formula, data = lalonde,
                  family = binomial(link = "logit"))$fitted.values

# Weights
lalonde$weight <- ifelse(lalonde$treat == 1,
                         pmin(lalonde$pscore, 1 - lalonde$pscore) / lalonde$pscore,
                     pmin(lalonde$pscore, 1 - lalonde$pscore) / (1 - lalonde$pscore))


Without the weights i would calculate and plot as follows:
cr <- cuminc(ftime = lalonde$time,
         fstatus = lalonde$event, 
             cencode = 0,
             group = lalonde$treat)

p <- ggcompetingrisks(fit = cr, 
                      multiple_panels = F, 
                      xlab = "Days", 
                      ylab = "Cumulative incidence of event",
                      title = "Competing Risks Analysis") 

As i am interested in the event adjusted for the competing risk, i exclude curves for the competing risk:
p$data <- p$data[p$data$event == 1, ]

p + labs(colour = "Group") 

which gives:

Question:

How is it possible to account for the weighting?
Maybe there is a workaround?
I can't imagine that it forces someone to use matching instead of weighting as there is no argument to implement the weights using cuminc.


Neither the cmprsk nor the survminer package allow the use of weights. However, you may use the adjustedcif() function from the adjustedCurves package instead. You could use the following code:
library(adjustedCurves)

# needs to be a factor variable in adjustecif()
lalonde$treat <- as.factor(lalonde$treat)

# fit propensity score model
ps_mod <- glm(treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + 
                re75 + re78, data=lalonde,
              family=binomial(link="logit"))

# calculate adjusted CIFs
adjcif <- adjustedcif(data=lalonde,
                      variable="treat",
                      ev_time="time",
                      event="event",
                      cause=1,
                      method="iptw",
                      treatment_model=ps_mod,
                      conf_int=TRUE)

# without 95% confidence intervals
plot(adjcif)

# with 95% confidence intervals
plot(adjcif, conf_int=TRUE)

Which will produce the following output:

The package also supports multiple other methods. See ?plot.adjustedcif for details on how the plot may be customized.

Thank you. Can i specify the weights myself? Like lalonde$weights?

The weights are specified according to the same model, so they should be the same if you used the correct formula for ATE weights. If you want to pass weights directly to the treatment_model argument you will have to use method="iptw_pseudo" though. Probably in conjunction with force_bounds=TRUE and iso_reg=TRUE.
